How should I prove my means for Schengen visa?
I am a PhD student.
I live in an EU country, Y where I want to bring my family. So, my family needs a long-term EU visa.
But my native country, X, doesn't have an embassy of Y. So, my family wants to apply for a Schengen visa at the embassy of another EU country, Z which has an embassy in X. The goal is to apply for temporary residency when my family arrives at Y.
I have a question in this regard:

How should I prepare my bank statement—only with the balance or monthly statement?
Do I need to show the source of my income?


I’m not familiar with the exact process but I’m far from convinced this is the right way to go about it, though details of the procedures for residence permits may vary by country. Telling in an application that you are coming to visit when you really mean to apply for residency does not seem like the right path, unless the country says this is the procedure to follow. Also they should not apply from embassy of Z just because they are present in the country, but only if Z acts as a representative for Y in the country.

Re: statements, they should always show all transactions (end of month balances are completely useless to them), and you should most definitely provide evidence of where the money comes from (e.g. salary slips), and of course they should match and be consistent. But a visit visa to cope see you without strong evidence of a reason to go back (which they obviously don’t have given your plans) is bound to fail.

Are you asking about a family reunification visa? I’m not sure why the cryptic ‘X, Y, Z’ identifiers are necessary; their use certainly doesn’t help gain an answer.

Go talk to the international office at your university. If they don't know the answer, they can certainly help you find out.

Most of the Asian/African applicants could easily fit the country names in X, Y and Z. So, no surprises!
As far as the source of income is concerned, one should strive to first comply the requirements as given on the website as difficult countries accept different types of proofs. Normally, the complete proof of source of income includes three docs: 3-6 months bank statements, salary slips for the same duration and finally and/or optionally you can attach the job offer letter clearly mentioning your pay package. This will give case handling officer a complete picture whether the source of income is legit.

I am a PhD student.

This answer only works if the applicant is a salaried employee

In this case, your PhD contract works as job contract provided it clearly mentions the amount you’d receive monthly salary/stipend.

In some countries, especially in Scandinavia, PhD scholars are salaried employees of the university.
